# DC motor voltage divider with NPN, diode, capacitor, and separate battery

Tags: dc-motor, voltage-divider, breadboard

I am trying to hook up a 9V battery to a 6V DC motor on a breadboard. The circuit on the breadboard has a 5V supply. Is the attached schematic correct in applying a 2/3 voltage drop from the battery to run the motor? I have the 1K resistor and emitter wired together and going to the breadboard ground, then my battery ground plugged into breadboard ground. Is that correct? Thanks.[image]

Comment: It is "correct" but will probably not do what you think it will. As soon as your motor tries to draw any significant current, almost all of the 9V will be dropped over the 2K resistor. In fact, you won't be able to draw more than ~4.5mA.

Comment: @tangrs how would I fix that then so I could run the motor while still dropping the voltage, lower resistors?

Comment: @tangrs I could do a 220 and 620 as I have a couple of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pulled a couple of DC motors off the shelf and wired them up to \$6\:\textrm{V}\$ DC and found that the current varied from perhaps \$100\:\textrm{mA}\$ (under little to no load) to about \$500\:\textrm{mA}\$ (when I held my fingers relatively tightly on the shaft as it rotated.) So that gives me a ballpark for the required current.

A typical \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ alkaline battery is from \$1\:\Omega\$ to \$2\:\Omega\$ of parasitic series resistance, depending on its state of charge. In addition, the battery's voltage will itself also vary quite a bit depending on its state of charge. But they are capable of supplying the level of currents I mentioned above. So, from some modest reasoning, I think you may make this work with these batteries.

The following schematic is not for anything but playing around with your motor. I'm going to assume that your battery will typically be providing about \$8.6\:\textrm{V}\$ under some load, when fresh. (I now know you have a TIP120 Darlington transistor.)

This circuit does ***not*** support being connected to an I/O port of a microcontroller. It is purely for playing with the motor, directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPiaZ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use a large valued capacitor for \$C_1\$, consistent with it being able to tolerate at least \$15\:\textrm{V}\$. Small values won't hurt, though. For \$C_2\$ your \$100\:\textrm{nF}\$ should be more than fine.

The point of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ is a voltage divider, not so different from what you already show in your own schematic. The difference here is that the divided voltage is applied to the base of the TIP120. The emitter will "follow" this voltage, dropping about \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$1.2\:\textrm{V}\$ from there. Because of the very high current gain of the TIP120, you can expect that the base current will be relatively small compared to the motor current. So it won't impact the voltage divider's voltage too much. Feel free to adjust \$R_1\$ or \$R_2\$ a little, as needed, to get the right voltage to the motor. But the values I show there should be not too far off.

If you have a potentiometer to add, feel free to wire it into the voltage divider circuit so that you can vary the motor voltage with it.

Use a voltmeter, if you have one, to observe the voltage between the negative terminal of your battery and the emitter of \$Q_1\$.

The idea of the above circuit is foremost to be simple and easy to wire up and where you can vary the value of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ a bit, perhaps. You should be able to arrange things with those resistors in order to get close to what you want, for some time while the battery is "mostly charged."

Please do NOT attempt this with a small, TO-92 packaged BJT. It will simply get hot, very fast, and probably just burn up and fizzle out on you in seconds, smoking a bit after. Not a good thing. You want a larger BJT for this task. The TIP120 you have should be fine, though. I'd probably add some metal to its tab, just so it stays a little cooler. But that's up to you.

\$C_2\$ will help absorb some spikes from the motor. That's the main reason I added it. Value isn't critical. But it should be around the size I mentioned (and that you seem to have), or a bit larger. You could add that reversed diode you had in your circuit if you want. I think \$C_2\$ is fine enough. Up to you, though.

Mostly, I'm hoping you can enjoy playing with this and see how it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the writeup. I have a potentiometer I can play with so I will try that. For C1 I have a 10 uF capcaitor that says 160 V so I am guessing it is rated for that high? BJT I am using is TIP120 and I have burned myself with one already :-( If I want my logic circuit (all analog, not using MCU) to activate the base, can I connect it to the parallel line across the top?

edit: nevermind, I know I can't connect the circuit signal to the parallel top. Would I just connect the resistor R1 in series with the above schematic and 1K resistor in series with circuit feeding into the base?

Comment: Also, for the potentiometer I wire the #1 to high and center to output. Then adjusting knob just adds more length of the resistance material to increase resistance correct? So CW = +resistance, CCW = -resistance

Comment: @NLhere The TIP120 is not an NPN, but actually two NPN transistors in a Darlington configuration. It's a very different device. For that, you can consider the idea of a resistor divider. Do you want a circuit that will operate from an MCU? If so, I need to know what MCU is involved so that I can work out the I/O voltages and current compliances.

Comment: That is not necessary, I don't plan on hooking up an MCU to it.

Comment: @NLhere Still, a voltage divider can now work just fine. I'll update the schematic.

Comment: @NLhere Changed. Hopefully, this is more like what you already understand. I'm using a voltage divider here, like you already did. Just applied a little differently.

Comment: Awesome discussion and advice. I appreciate your input, time to start wiring :-)

Comment: @NLhere Any success yet?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately I was limited with resistors so I just put the potentiometer in series with my circuit and didn't run a voltage divider. I used the 100nF capacitor across my motor and it helped a ton with reducing noise that I was previously getting across my board. I didn't use the C1 capacitor, although from my basic understanding it is used to help smooth voltage changes across the circuit? In my other circuit powered by an AC/DC converter at 5V, I used three 16 uF capacitors across my breadboard rails for the same reason but intuitively don't really know if they did anything

Comment: @NLhere Glad to hear that the capacitor across the motor helped. It is often a "good idea" as it "absorbs" energy like a sponge. Too much of a good idea can become a bad idea. But that value seemed good to me, so I'm glad it worked okay. C1 don't worry about. That is mostly because 9V batteries can get a little weak and a capacitor gives a slight momentary boost of sorts. But that isn't all that useful for running a motor, anyway. So just dump the idea and don't look back. (However, it may help reduce noise making it backwards into other circuits, if the 9V was also used elsewhere.)

Comment: @NLhere If you feel this is a good enough answer, you can check it off as such. (Don't do that if you are waiting for others to write here as well, though.) I think you get a couple of points for it, too.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new to this site. It won't let me check it off though as an answer because my rep is too low, once my rep is high enough ill upvote this post as I appreciate the thorough explanation

Comment: @NLhere I'll fix that, I think. Just upped you so you have some pts to work with. It's also the "check mark" and not the "up" or "down" triangle that does it. You may be able to click the "up" and "down" triangle, separately, as well. I don't know.